# Can not move row after performing "OrderBy" in Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have created a small script that removes and inserts row to first place in a Kendo Grid.  However, every time I order by any column, that particular script does not work anymore and I can not move any row after that.  I have tried reading the dataSource again, also tried refreshing the grid, but without anything happening.

Here is my script function (which b.t.w. works very well before orderby column):

```
function onFetchItem(gridName) {
    $("#errorMsg").text("");
    var ids = gridName.split("_");
    var item = $("#itemSearch_" + ids[1]).val();
    var grid = $("#" + gridName).data("kendoGrid");

    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    var dataItem = $.grep(data, function (d) {
        if (d.Item == item.toUpperCase()) {
            grid.dataSource.remove(d);
            grid.dataSource.insert(0, d);
            //grid.dataSource.read();
            return d;
        }
        return null;
    });
    //grid.refresh();
    if (dataItem[0] == null) {
        $("#errorMsg").text("none");
    } 
}
```

Like I said, I tried reading the dataSource again and refresh the grid as you can see in my commented code.  When I do that, the row item bounces back to it´s original place, probably due to reading the dataSource again.  How can I move row item after orderby action on the grid?

**I´ve also created a small playground to try out similar code to mine:**

http://jsbin.com/sazah/1/edit

Try it, order by the first column and see that I can not move any record after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a sort, that sort still applies after doing the `remove` and `insert` so it is not that the `move` doesn't work, the question is that you are still sorting and then it seem that doesn't work.

[Example 1](http://jsbin.com/pilinaha/1/): I've added an `order` column to the data and I have two elements with the same `order`. If you sort by `order`, `"baz"` element is now second but if you click on `move` button it will go to the first position since it is possible having it first but still ordered.

```
dataSource: [
    { order: 1, foo: "foo" },
    { order: 2, foo: "bar" },
    { order: 1, foo: "baz" }
],
```

[Example 2](http://jsbin.com/pilinaha/2/): On this example, you have the same `order` column but this time `"baz"` element has a `order` value that is not the minimum. Here if you sort by `order` and then click on move you will see that `"baz"` moves to the first element with that same `order` value.

```
dataSource: [
    { order: 1, foo: "foo" },
    { order: 2, foo: "bar" },
    { order: 2, foo: "baz" }
],
```

[Example 3](http://jsbin.com/pilinaha/3/): But if you want to move it to the first position, you need to remove the order by calling `grid.dataSource.sort({});` before `remove` and `insert`.

```
function move(col) {
    var item = "baz";
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"); 

    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    var dataItem = $.grep(data, function (d) {
            if (d.foo == item) {
            console.log(col);
            grid.dataSource.sort({});
            grid.dataSource.remove(d);
            grid.dataSource.insert(0, d);
            //grid.dataSource.read();
            return d;
            }
            return false;
            });
    //grid.refresh();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @OneBai, that did the trick.  I actually went with clearing the sorting as you suggested, but I must say it was quite clever creating an order value for the list.  Thanx again  :)